# How to wait for callback until user press any button on the bootboxJS prompt instead of executing the remaining script after showing the prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt, bootbox, input-mask

This function is in a very big hierarchy of js functions so can't use html from views else I will lose all parameters as there are many parameters being passed in each script.

Using bootbox.js for this prompt -- because it has password masking in the prompt the not working code. I need to wait for callback instead of completing the execution of remaining script after showing the prompt.

```
function authorize() {
  alert("Script has started...");
  var final_result = 0;
  bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a password input!",
    inputType: 'password',
    callback: function(result)
    {
      if (result!=null) 
      {
        final_result = 1;
      } else {
        final_result = 0;
      }
    }
  });
 alert("calling XYZ");  
function xyz();
alert("Script has finished... final result is" + final_result);  
 }
```

The working code with default JavaScript prompt -- want like this (using bootboxjs just to mask the input as I'm using this for password):

```
function authorize() {

  alert("Script has started...");
  var final_result = 0;
  let text = prompt("This is a prompt with a password input!", "")
  if (text!= null) {
    final_result = 1;
  } else {
    final_result = 0;
  }
  alert("calling xyz" );  
function xyz();
 alert("Script has finished... final result is" + final_result );  
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the text you have written. Would it be worth showing an image of the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Hello, the problem is that after showing the prompt using bootboxjs there is a callback in it when user enter password and press ok , call back happens perfectly but the script after showing prompt doesn't wait for the callback and executes the remaining script and exit from the script, after showing the prompt can we wait until user press any key ?, Just like the default JavaScript prompt which returns the value entered in the prompt... The default JavaScript prompt returns the value and until then it blocks the remaining script to run... Need The default behavior of prompt()....

Comment: Lovely. Please [edit that into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73917520/edit), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-note-nonblocking), many times:

> All Bootstrap modals (and therefore Bootbox modals), unlike native alerts, confirms, or prompts, are asynchronous; meaning, the events which Bootstrap generates are non-blocking events. Because of this limitation, code that should not be evaluated until a user has dismissed your dialog must be called within the callback function of the dialog.

Given your example, this is what I'm assuming you're after:

```js
function authorize() {
  alert("Script has started...");
  
  let final_result = 0;
  bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a password input!",
    inputType: 'password',
    callback: function(result) {
      if (result != null) {
        final_result = 1;
      } 
      else {
        final_result = 0;
      }
      
      // call xyz() here, with your prompt's value
      xyz(final_result);
    }
  });
}

// Changed this to accept a parameter, to match what 
// it seems you're trying to do
function xyz(final_result) {
    alert("Script has finished... final result is" + final_result);  
}
```

To reiterate: **Bootstrap modals are just positioned `<div>` elements, and the `modal()` function is just hiding and showing them.**

If you really want a customizable prompt that does block program execution, your only option is `<dialog>` ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)). It's only recently gained enough [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#browser_compatibility) to be usable, though, so use at your own risk.